# nginx proxy pass express routes

Tags: express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

With the following config and code, if I goto https://domain.co/api/yo

it looks for a '/api/yo' route in the express app rather than just '/yo'

how do I config NGINX so that express sees https://domain.co/api/yo as '/yo'?

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    root /var/www/domain.co;
    index index.html;
    server_name domain.co www.domain.co;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/yo', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Nginx and Express route had to match for me

nginx:
location /api

express:
app.get('/api', ...)